# read cookie value in jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have called one php page inside the iframe

I have stored some values in cookies.I want to read that cookies values from that page to other page.

I used jQuery to read cookie.

```
var value = $.cookie('artname');
```

'artname' is the cookie name.

But it displaying null value because cookies path is different,path is `"/v/abcfile/frontend/".`

But the path for the other cookies on the page i am trying to get is "/.

I tried with this: `top.jQuery.cookie('artname');`
Its still showing me the same.

how can I get value of cookie?

Answer (score 12):

just use the path property

```
$.cookie("example",  { path: '/' });
```

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

cheers

Comment: This is for setting the cookie at the desired path, not for reading it.